# How can I implement a console command with zf3 and symfony console

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework3

The zend console is deprecated. I will use symfony/console (as suggested): `composer require symfony/console`

With the ZF 2 & 3 I have some years of experience. With Symfony I have done different things, even several console commands.

My skeleton for a symfony console command:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class InstallCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var string The name of the command (the part after "bin/console")
     */
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:modulename-install';

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->addArgument('test', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Only a test.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $text = 'your argument: ' . $input->getArgument('test');
        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

**1. problem**: symfony console has none `*Action()`'s in classes `*Command`. How can i configure a route?

**2 problem**: there is no `/vendor/bin/console` file.

How can I implement symfony 4.x console command in Zend Framework 3?

...the internet is silent on this topic

Comment: There's [a package](https://packagist.org/packages/eth8505/zf-symfony-console) that claims integration between the two.

Comment: @msg good idea, but this is not working with output: Application not returned from index.php PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getServiceManager()
...always index.php return nothing

Answer (score 0):

According to [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) each console command is a separate class inherited from `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` and you need to implement your command runtime code inside `execute()` method. Because of this there is no routing is involved. Actually you can think about your console command class itself as an action because Symfony's console Application [includes routing](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/8b0ae5742ce9aaa8b0075665862c1ca397d1c1d9/Application.php#L612).

Question about `bin/console` file is a bit tricky. Normally when you're working with Symfony 4 itsef you're usually using [Symfony Flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html). Flex itself connects Composer packages with so called "recipes" that resides into [separate service](https://flex.symfony.com/). Flex uses these recipes to allow automatic configuration of packages that are installed for Symfony application through Composer. Because of this fact `bin/console` command is not a part of Composer package, but instead part of Flex recipe for [`symfony/console`](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/console) package. You can fine it out by yourself inside [official recipes](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/master/symfony/console/3.3/bin) repository.

I have almost zero knowledge about ZF3, but in a case if you're using console as a standalone component you may decide either to deal with Symfony's [DI container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) and store all services (including commands) inside it or to manually register every command in console application by using [Application::add()](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/8b0ae5742ce9aaa8b0075665862c1ca397d1c1d9/Application.php#L466) method.

Comment: The console file from the official recipes require symfony and load nothing from ZF3. That is why I can not use it.
And with console Application i have nothing from ZF3.
For me, it looks like it can not work together at all.

Comment: @Flying Minor nitpick: bin/console is delivered as part of the Symfony framework.  No direct relation to Flex or composer.

Comment: `console` command from recipe requires `symfony/framework-bundle` which is way too much for you. But you can use its contents as a base of your own implementation. Main difference is that you need to use `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` instead of one, provided by `FrameworkBundle`. You will also need to use own implementation of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface` for kernel that, in its turn will require some container implementaion. But since containers are interoperable thanks to PSR-11 you can use ZF3 container here

Comment: @Cerad I agree, but bitkorn was asking why there is no such file in `vendor`, but to be able to answer where is it came from I had to explain what Flex recipes are.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a realllllyyy long time since I created/updated this, so not too sure how this all fit together anymore.

But! I can give you an example.

---

This is [this no longer maintained module](https://github.com/Hounddog/DoctrineDataFixtureModule) on Github which I found quite handy in the days of ZF2, and I've sort of upgraded it in a few projects of mine where I wanted it, but never into a fully blown ZF3 module. But it works :)

Purpose: run fixtures (yea I know, `php bin/console doc:fix:load -n` in SF4 :p)

If I remember right, you could use this with: `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module data-fixture:import` from the project root and have your Fixture classes registered like so:

```
...,
'doctrine' => [
    ...,
    'fixture' => [
        FQCN::class,
        FQCN2::class,
    ],
],
```

So, here it goes (if you copy this, mind the namespaces for folder structure, based on ZF3 with all in `src/` folder):

A `Module.php` class:

```
<?php

namespace DoctrineFixture;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
use DoctrineFixture\Command\ImportCommand;
use DoctrineFixture\Service\FixtureFactory;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface
{    
    public function init(ModuleManager $e)
    {
        $events = $e->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        // Attach to helper set event and load the entity manager helper.
        $events->attach(
            'doctrine',
            'loadCli.post',
            function (EventInterface $e) {
                /* @var $cli \Symfony\Component\Console\Application */
                $cli = $e->getTarget();

                /* @var $sm ContainerInterface */
                $sm    = $e->getParam('ServiceManager');
                $em    = $sm->get(EntityManager::class);
                $paths = $sm->get('doctrine.configuration.fixtures');

                $importCommand = new ImportCommand();
                $importCommand->setObjectManager($em);
                $importCommand->setPaths($paths);
                ConsoleRunner::addCommands($cli);
                $cli->addCommands(
                    [
                        $importCommand,
                    ]
                );
            }
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                'doctrine.configuration.fixtures' => new FixtureFactory(),
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];

        foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/config/*.php') as $filename) {
            $config = array_merge_recursive($config, include $filename);
        }

        return $config;
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return [
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
                'namespaces' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Class `ImportCommand`

```
<?php

namespace DoctrineFixture\Command;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Command for generate migration classes by comparing your current database schema
 * to your mapping information.
 */
class ImportCommand extends Command
{
    const PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE = 0; // 1 = DELETE FROM, 2 = TRUNCATE

    /** @var array */
    protected $paths;

    /** @var ObjectManager|EntityManager */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @return int|null|void
     */
    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $loader = new Loader();
        $purger = new ORMPurger();

        if ($input->getOption('purge-with-truncate')) {
            $purger->setPurgeMode(self::PURGE_MODE_TRUNCATE);
        }

        $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->getObjectManager(), $purger);

        foreach ($this->getPaths() as $key => $value) {
            $loader->loadFromDirectory($value);
        }

        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures(), $input->getOption('append'));
    }

    public function getPaths(): array
    {
        return $this->paths;
    }

    public function setPaths(array $paths): ImportCommand
    {
        $this->paths = $paths;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectManager|EntityManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager|EntityManager $objectManager
     */
    public function setObjectManager($objectManager): ImportCommand
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Register command
     */
    protected function configure(): void
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this->setName('data-fixture:import')
             ->setDescription('Import Data Fixtures')
             ->setHelp(
                 <<<EOT
The import command Imports data-fixtures
EOT
             )
             ->addOption('append', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Append data to existing data.')
             ->addOption('purge-with-truncate', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Truncate tables before inserting data');
    }

}
```

And a class `FixtureFactory` to tie it all together:

```
<?php

namespace DoctrineFixture\Service;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class FixtureFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array|object
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $options = $container->get('config');
        if (! isset($options['doctrine']['fixture'])) {

            return [];
        }

        return $options['doctrine']['fixture'];
    }
}
```